# Receiving bytearray gets splitted

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an android app which receives an bytearray via Bluetooth from an `Asuro` which is a little robot.

This bytearray is a protocol for commands and therefore has a fixed size of 15
Furthermore the app is sending the bytearray to the Asuro and the Asuro sends it back.

However this bytearray gets split if I use the read(byte[],0,15) function and give this array to Log.d.

See the code below:

```
public void run() {
Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[15];
int bytes = 0;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (true) {
    try {
    // Read from the InputStream
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, 15);
    if (buffer[0] != 0) {
        Log.d("Asuro-Android", "Input :" + Arrays.toString(buffer));
    }
    buffer = new byte[15];      
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
connectionLost();
break;
}
}
}
```

I am sending to Asuro:

```
Output: [58, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 51, 48, 48, 48, 48]
```

Connections etc work. to simplify it i create an array and flush it into the outputstream.

But I am getting:

```
Input :[58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Input :[48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Input :[48, 48, 48, 48, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Could this be an error on my part (app) or can this only be an error on asuro's part?

Comment: Have you try read 150 bytes instead 15?

Comment: we tried with 1024 and 2048 but it still got split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of the Bluetooth SPP profile , it doesn't provide frame boundaries.
So it can get split by the sender SPP itself or the receiver depending on its buffer capacity etc.
In your case since the packet is always fixed size you could do a simple re-assembly or for a more general case add your won header and reassemble a frame.

Comment: thx for your insight. by frame you mean array? so i filter for valid entries which would be != zero in my case and create a new array.
i will look further into this (most likely the robot has a very limited capacity).

Comment: could you give me a hint why the first array has 1 entry only? i would assume that the bufferlimit is reached at the end resulting in a full first array and a less filled (1 entry for example) later?

Comment: I am guessing that the application on the robot is probably writing it it this order. What does the 1st byte represent ? (Is it a comamnd code ?)